# How do I pass interfaces as varargs parameters to a method in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, variadic-functions

Is there a way to pass interfaces as varargs parameters to a method in groovy?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
interface Handler {
    void handle(String)
}

def foo(Handler... handlers) {
    handlers.each { it.handle('Hello!') }
}

foo({ print(it) }, { print(it.toUpperCase()) })
```

When I run the following code, I get the error:

`No signature of method: ConsoleScript8.foo() is applicable for argument    types: (ConsoleScript8$_run_closure1, ConsoleScript8$_run_closure2) values:    [ConsoleScript8$_run_closure1@4359df7, ConsoleScript8$_run_closure2@4288c46b]`

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java-style `...`-varargs are just `Handler[]` to the JVM.  So the shortest way to make that work is:

```
foo([{ print(it) }, { print(it.toUpperCase()) }] as Handler[])
```

(Pass them as a list cast to `Handler[]`)

Comment: @Opal with just one handler passed, your solution is shorter - so returned the favour ;)

Comment: @cfrick This seems elegant enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This way:

```
interface Handler {
   void handle(String)
}

def foo(Handler... handlers) {
   handlers.each { it.handle('Hello!') }
}

foo({ print(it) } as Handler, { print(it.toUpperCase()) } as Handler)
```

You need to do the casting.

Comment: Accepted the previous answer because it looked more elegant, but your solution gives me code assist for `it` in IntelliJ, so have an upvote.